# Conflict with Debian version

Tags: debian, apt, debian-wheezy, debian-stretch, lsb

On a server I set up a few years ago, typing `cat /etc/lsb-release` gives me the following result:

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=7
DISTRIB_CODENAME=
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=
```

And `lsb_release -a` displays:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    7
Codename:   stretch
```

It seems like the system is not very sure whether it is a Debian 9 (Stretch) or Debian 7 (Wheezy). Some packages that should be available with Stretch cannot be found with `apt-cache search`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe check your /etc/apt/sources.list content and think of upgrading properly to stretch or buster.

Comment: Did the upgrade, everything seems much more consistent now.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/lsb-release` file is largely ignored on most modern systems. The usual source of truth would be the information provided by the `lsb_release` command. However, neither of these have anything at all to do with which packages you see available. That portion is handled exclusively by the apt sources, which can be found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

You can start by examining `/etc/apt/sources.list` and checking which release is being used for new packages. The [SourcesList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) page on the Debian Wiki has more information about the format of that file and how to update it.